# What is the easiest fix to the "There are staged changes in the repository, updates let uncommitted" message in Git

Tags: git

I have a git repository with two remotes and custom remote for pushing to both when I call `git push all`. On my last push I receive this message and any additional pushes result in ...

```
Everything up-to-date
Everything up-to-date
```

Any way to fix this. The problem is the message I get every time I try to push now:

```
There are staged changes in the repository, updates let uncommitted
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Sounds like everything is up-to-date on your repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `git status`. You will probably see some files listed as 'staged' (i.e. you did `git add` them before). Those are not yet committed and therefore are not something `git push` would propagate upstream, which it warns you about.

You need to review the staged changes (use `git diff --cached`) and if they are in order, commit them with `git commit`. Once you've done that `git push` will attempt to push your changes upstream.